# Huffman code length

Tags: hashtable, huffman-code

I want to build a huffman tree and assign a code to all the 255 byte values based on their frequencies. But For my application I need a hash table to get the code for a byte in constant time. But in worst case the tree may be so unbalanced that certain bytes have a very large key (even 254 bit long) . So maintaining a hash table is being very difficult. The code requires high performance and so stroing them as a string won't work. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: 1) why use a hash table for a byte-sized input, why not a simple array? 2) unless your programming language has native support for 256-bit integers (most don't) you will need to use some sort of string arrangement to store the output codes.

Comment: "All the 255 byte values"? There are 256 byte values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need a hash table for 256 values? Simply have a 256-entry table where you directly index the code for each byte.

Each code is at most 32 bytes long, so just have a table of 256 entries, each with a fixed number of 33 bytes per entry. 8448 bytes. The first byte of the 33 being the length of the code in bits, and the remaining bytes being the code, of which you only use the requisite number of bits for each.